# how to update one table with results from another mysql query

Tags: mysql

i am seeking help on updating one column in a table with results from another query.

table names:

```
saleitems - fields are (itemid,quantity,saledate) 
stockbuffers - fields are (itemid,bufferquantity)
```

i am getting the buffer quantity with the following query from sale items table:

```
SELECT (SUM(saleitems.quantity / 6)) * 6 FROM saleitems WHERE saleitems.saledate BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(),interval 180 day) AND NOW() GROUP BY saleitems.itemid
```

i want to update the column buffer quantity from the above query's result. can anyone help. greatly appreaciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update query as:

```
Update stockbuffers set bufferquantity =(SELECT (SUM(saleitems.quantity / 6)) * 6 FROM saleitems WHERE saleitems.saledate BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(),interval 180 day) AND NOW() GROUP BY saleitems.itemid)
```

its just a sample and not have been tested.

Comment: how would the query know which row to update since there are two tables. where do i place the join query to join the tables since itemid is a common field in both tables

Comment: The query will be updating the stockbuffer table as we have specified in the code as "Update stockbuffers"